# How do I exclude the current post from listing in recent posts

Tags: posts, exclude

I list my two most recent posts from a widget on the sidebar. When I'm viewing one of these posts from single.php, I want that post to be excluded from the list and instead show the next post in order.

single.php looks something like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    [Content]

    <?php endwhile; else : ?>

    [If no post is found]

<?php endif; ?>
```

and here's the code in the PHP-widget:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=2' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

    [Recent posts]

<?php endwhile;?>
```

**Edit - the solution:**

```
<?php global $post; $args = array('showposts' => 2, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )); query_posts( $args ); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    [Recent posts]

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>
```

Comment: see the first question in related posts column over there --->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post__not_in arg should work for you:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts' => 5,
'offset' => 0,
'category' => 7,
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
);
$myposts2 = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: I finally got it working, thanks. Edited my first post.

Comment: glad I could help :)